# how to change mysql_result($res, 0, "url"); to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know how to use mysqli_result like past.

is this ok? how is correct?

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id`,`usrid`,`url` FROM site WHERE state = 'popup' AND creditsp >= 1 AND (cth < cph || cph=0) order by rand() limit 1");
$urll = mysqli_result($res, 0, "url");
$ownerid = mysqli_result($res, 0, "usrid");
$siteidd = mysqli_result($res, 0, "id");
```

Comment: @mohammed `$urll = $res['url']`, `$ownerid = $res['usrid']`, and `$siteidd = $res['id']`

Comment: @AdamElsodaney - how did you know what his name was?? I had to use google translate...

Comment: @raidenace I'm half-Egyptian, I can read Arabic (but can't speak it) ;)

Comment: @AdamElsodaney - man that's cool...I'd love to know multiple languages - both spoken and programming :)

Comment: Yes you called me right :) muhammad = محمد

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fetch_assoc` on the result:

```
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$urll = $row['url'];
$ownerid = $row['usrid'];
$siteidd = $row['id'];
```

If there are more than one row, then:

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    // process $row
}
```

Comment: how to use $urll = mysqli_result($res, 1, "url"); or $urll = mysqli_result($res, 2, "url");  ?

Comment: @محمدعلیپورفتحکوهی, use a while loop like in the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4 now supports function array dereferencing:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

so, in order to get the results from sql you need to use mysqli_fetch_assoc() function.

Usage can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp

**________Small Example________**

Suppose we have a DB:

Id   Name       Age     Occupation
1.   William    11      Student
2.   Uname      14      Student
3.   Yem        22      Teacher

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM persons";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));  \\returns an associative array to the row variable. You can use foreach loop as well to loop throgh the various data items.
{
echo $row["Id"] . "<br>";
echo $row["Name"] . "<br>";
echo $row["Age"] . "<br>";
echo $row["Occupation"] . "<br>";
}
```